# CentOS 6.3. libpam.so 32bit not found

Tags: centos, packages

I try to install `DB2 fixpack 6` into `CentOS 6.3 x64`. I have already installed `DB2 9.7`. When I begin to install fixpack (running `installFixPack`) I get an error:

> "The 32-bit library file libpam.so is not found on the system"

. But I already installed and x86 and x64 packages of libpam.so.0.

I can check it using `rpm -q pam` command,

and output is

`pam-1.1.1-10.el6_2.1.x86_64

     pam-1.1.1-10.el6_2.1.i686`

Where is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the existence of the file `/lib/libpam.so.0` -- It needs to be there.

Maybe also run `ldconfig -v`, then try the installer again.

Comment: yes both file exist: `/lib/libpam.so.0` and `/lib64/libpam.so.0`. Running `ldconfig -v` not help. But installer wrote that it need `libpam.so`, not `libpam.so.0`  - may be there problem? I new in linux, so I don't found package `libpam.so` and I think installer wrote about `libpam.so.0`, not about `libpam.so`

Comment: @MyTitle This is a case where you should probably symlink to `libpam.so.0` with `ln -s /lib/libpam.so.0 /lib/libpam.so` and see if that works to get through the installation.

Comment: Very BIG thanks. You solved my problem. Seems, it were error of Db2 programmers